# Kibana array hierarchy in pie chart

Tags: arrays, pie-chart, kibana-5

I got logs with arrays in Elastic Index.
each cell in the array represents region.
The higher the index, the higher resolution of the region.
For Example:
[Earth,USA,NYS,NYC,Manhattan]

I would like to visualize the places in a pie chart, so each level corresponds to the matched index in the array

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPcAI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with field of type array. I recommend you to create field name region , field name subregion, and so on,then create visualisation with sub bucket and you will get what you want